My address is spelled wrong on my ESTA form
I’m from England and will be travelling to the States in a few weeks.
My address is spelled wrong (just a typo) on my ESTA form but everything else is perfect.
Will I have any problems if use it at the airport? I’m worried they will deny me entry.

Is the question about home address or where you will staying in the US?

It's not an issue.  Quite frankly I'm not sure why they even ask for the address, it's not validated in any way, shape or form, and you are not even required to update it if you come back for another trip and stay somewhere else.

Okay Thank you so much

@CharlotteBrydges Please accept the answer by clicking on the ✔️ if this worked for you!
